# On Google App Engine is it possible JDOQL Date without using a parameterised query?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Is it possible to do a date query in JDOQL without using a parameterrised query on Google App Engine.

I am trying to write some generic code that looks something like this, where criteria is just a string, and I would like to be able to specify anything - with this piece of code not needing to to know much about the underlying data.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(tClass);
        if (criteria!=null) {
            query.setFilter(criteria);
        }
```

criteria could be "startdate = 'someproperlyformatteddatetime'"

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, [GAE JDO queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) support JDOQL. You could simply do something like this: `q.setFilter("height <= 200")` or `q.setFilter("name == 'Smith'")`, where you would programmatically assemble the JDOQL filter string. The only downside is that you need to know the type of parameters (as saved in Datastore), as strings need to be enclosed in single or double quotes.

Note that all [restrictions on queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Restrictions_on_Queries) still apply.

Also, if you want to query on [multiple properties where you also use inequality operator](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Index_Definition_and_Structure), then you need to [define compound indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig) beforehand.

**Update:** JDOQL literal parameter specification works with string and numeric values; all other value types must use parameter substitution. You could still do that programmatically.

Another workaround would be if you use `long` instead of `Date` and convert dates to UNIX timestamps (which are of type long).

Comment: Thanks Peter. This question was specifically about querying a Date type field. What syntax would I use for that?

Comment: Ok - thanks for the confirmation - I had already switched to using long in my impatience :-) but now I know I can call that a concious design decision. Thanks again